# kotlinx.serialization , Encode Decode SnapshotStateList

Tags: kotlin, serialization, deserialization, kotlinx.serialization

In Jetpack Compose , **SnapshotStateList** is a derived class from List but whenever I try to put Serializable annotation over it , it says **"Serializer Not Found For This Class , To use contextual use @Contextual annotation with type or property"**

I have a class ListContainer , I want to make serializable , it only contains a list of items which is a **SnapshotStateList** and can be smart casted to List but I don't know how to tell kotlin serializer to cast it to a List / use simple List serializer !

Comment: As `SnapshotStateList` is not serializable, I believe you need to create a custom serializer for it and use it as described here: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serializers.md#serializing-3rd-party-classes . And even if `SnapshotStateList` implements a list, it can only help with serializing, but not with deserializing.

Comment: >but I don't know how to tell kotlin serializer to cast it

As usual, with [unsafe cast operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html#unsafe-cast-operator)
`private inline fun <reified T> encode(snapshotStateList: SnapshotStateList<T>) = Json.encodeToString(snapshotStateList as List<T>)`

Comment: its inside another class which has serializable annotation over it !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class SnapshotListSerializer<T>(private val dataSerializer:KSerializer<T>) :
    KSerializer<SnapshotStateList<T>> {

    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = ListSerializer(dataSerializer).descriptor

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: SnapshotStateList<T>) {
        encoder.encodeSerializableValue(ListSerializer(dataSerializer), value as List<T>)
    }

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): SnapshotStateList<T> {
        val list = mutableStateListOf<T>()
        val items = decoder.decodeSerializableValue(ListSerializer(dataSerializer))
        list.addAll(items)
        return list
    }
}
```

I am not sure if it works but this is what I came up with , I'll update the answer accordingly